# Flash overlapping / wmode Issue

Tags: html, flash, google-chrome, z-index, wmode

I experience the very known flash / html overlay issue in **Google Chrome** (16.0.912.75 m) and **Safari** (5.1.1). As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313364/google-chrome-flash-and-z-index-wrong-behaviour) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050999/youtube-iframe-wmode-issue) I have set the `wmode` attribute to `transparent` - and tried `opaque`, as well. Unfortunately both didn't do the trick.

I have also added `type="application/x-shockwave-flash"` like it is suggested [here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=2ca277b12bc29e35&hl=en)

Here is the code currently responsible for the embedding.

```
<iframe wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
    width="760" height="427" 
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Xedbog6_3L0?rel=0&hd=1?wmode=transparent" 
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this problem is not reproductive in Safari 5.1.2 and Firefox 9.0.1 (Mac versions). Without knowing your browser, I can only say that since you are using an `iframe` tag to point a page where Flash is actually embedded, `wmode` has no effect in your current DOM document, as it is not a valid property of `iframe` tag (it belongs to `embed` tag). You'd need to set css property `display` to `block` value on the `iframe` tag in order to to make a browser treat your `iframe` as a standard layout object. Then, you could set the layer distribution and positioning via CSS.

Comment: Many thanks. I wasn't aware of the wmode attribute being not effective for iframe. Yikes. ...
I've added the display: block setting to the iframe and explicitly set the z-index to 0 (the navigation has z-index: 99). 
Any further advice is very appreciated. (I've added the browser versions above).

Comment: Update: Due to your help I found this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820325/overlay-opaque-div-over-youtube-iframe) and solved the issue. Thanks.