# Flash lay over position: fixed element in chrome

Tags: css, flash, google-chrome

Normally, I'm using firefox when I'm writing css codes. But my codes have problem when using chrome.

My fixed menu:

```
header{
  background-color: #2bd5ec;
  overflow:hidden;
  line-height: 200%;
  top:0;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

And when i'm scrolling the page my swf file is on behind.
My css codes of swf file.

```
#swfFile{width: 500px;height: 500px;}
```

But when I'm using chrome swf file is in front of menu.
What I have to change?

Comment: Can you post the HTML part, too?

Comment: @Mark there are my codes: http://pastebin.com/3E8cyxYy

Comment: @user1648692 Please only provide the resulting, relevant HTML. Not the whole PHP file.

Comment: @Abody97 all of my codes: http://pastebin.com/kHtkqmeq

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Chrome, Flash and z-index wrong behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313364/google-chrome-flash-and-z-index-wrong-behaviour)

Comment: @AndreasKöberle solved. I have added wmode="tranparent" parameter to embed tag. Write this as answer. I'll vote as best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a problem of your CSS but of your swf object. You have to set the `wmode` of your embed to `transparent`. Otherwise it will lay over all other elements.

```
<object>
    <embed wmode="transparent" height="550" width="733">
</object>
```

Comment: I have added this code to <object>'s inside. Anything was changed.

Comment: sorry has to `transparent` not `opaque`

Comment: add this link to your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313364/google-chrome-flash-and-z-index-wrong-behaviour

Answer (score 2):

it is a chrome bug. 
chrome can not handle a div with position:fixed AND overflow:hidden AND a flashobject inside that div.
stripped example (the wmode-param is not necessary to have a problem):

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>chromebug</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div style="min-height:10000px;">CONTENT</div>
  <div style="position: fixed;overflow:hidden;background-color: #000000; bottom: 0; left: 0;">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width='400px;' height='100px' data="banner.swf">
     <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    </object>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

online here: http://bytepirates.com/cbug.html

solution: remove the overflow:hidden