# an issue with a joomla 2.5 menu

Tags: flash, z-index, wmode

I have a problem with a menu on joomla 2.5, the sub menu appears under the flash content as the image below

[image]

Any body can help?

I am using the below code to ember the swf inside the joomla site

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // <![CDATA[        

    var so = new SWFObject("../../ammap/ammap.swf", "ammap", "100%", "100%", "8", "#f2f2f2");

so.addVariable("path", "../../ammap/");

    so.addVariable("data_file", escape("ammap_data.xml"));

so.addVariable("settings_file", escape("ammap_settings.xml"));      

    so.addVariable("preloader_color", "#999999");

    so.write("flashcontent");

    // ]]>

</script>
```

Comment: There's no way anyone can help without more details of your code and approach.

Comment: I am sorry, this is my mistake, I have added additional info

Answer (score 0):

It's a z-index issue that's common with Flash content (YouTube, etc.). Try adding

```
?wmode=transparent
```

to the end of your source URL(s).

[Google Chrome, Flash and z-index wrong behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313364/google-chrome-flash-and-z-index-wrong-behaviour)

http://forums.adobe.com/message/4123098

Comment: thanks for help, I am using this code to embed the swf with xml data files
 <script type="text/javascript">

  // <![CDATA[  

  var so = new SWFObject("../../ammap/ammap.swf?wmode=transparent", "ammap", "100%", "100%", "8", "#f2f2f2");
 But it's not working yet