# Spry Menus display under Image viewer in Safari

Tags: flash, menu, show, slide, spry

I am designing a page using dreamveaver CS3 and I have the following problem:

Thanks to dreamveaver I have created a vertical menu bar with submenus opening up, next to it I have used the Media>Image Viewer Menu to create a Slideshow. 
It works great except for in Safari (on Windows) where the submenus are hidden under the slideshow.

After searching online I found several peolpe with this issue, and the usual suggestion was to increase the z-index on the sub menu. I have tried doing that but the browsers seam to ignore this property (for example if I look on inspect element on google chrome, which anyhow displays correctly, I find all the other properties defined for that div but not the z-index).

I also though of decreasing the z-index of the flash file, but I am not sure how to do that.

I would appreciate any help.

sorry danii, obviously I am new to this forum thing so I do not quite know how to reply to you. Anyway I did not have enough place to put the all code in my comment to you answer so here it is:

AC_FL_RunContent( 'codebase','HERE IS LINK TO ://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0','width','820','height','250','align','absmiddle','src','/sciences/terre/slideshow','quality','high','flashvars','flashlet={imageLinkTarget:\'_blank\',captionFont:\'Verdana\',titleFont:\'Verdana\',showControls:false,frameShow:false,slideDelay:5,captionSize:0,captionColor:#333333,titleSize:0,transitionsType:\'Fade\',titleColor:#333333,slideAutoPlay:true,imageURLs:[\'/sciences/terre/images/front_slider/river-landscape_820x250.jpg\',\'/sciences/terre/images/front_slider/arctic_820x250.jpg\',\'/sciences/terre/images/front_slider/chaiten_820x250.jpg\',\'/sciences/terre/images/front_slider/coast_terrace_uw820x250.jpg\',\'/sciences/terre/images/front_slider/greem.JPG\',\'/sciences/terre/images/front_slider/Green_river_valley_820x250.JPG\',\'/sciences/terre/images/front_slider/matternhorn_820X250.jpg\',\'/sciences/terre/images/front_slider/pebbles_820x250.jpg\'],slideLoop:true,frameThickness:0,imageLinks:[\'HERE IS LINK TO://macromedia.com/\',\'HERE IS LINK TO://macromedia.com/\',\'HERE IS LINK TO://macromedia.com/\'],frameColor:#333333,bgColor:#FFFFFF,imageCaptions:[]}','pluginspage','HERE IS LINK TO://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash','scale','exactfit','flash_component','ImageViewer.swc','wmod','transparent','movie','/sciences/terre/slideshow' ); //end AC code
     
     
     
        
       
       
       
       http://macromedia.com/'],frameColor:#333333,bgColor:#FFFFFF,imageCaptions:[]}" />
        http://macromedia.com/'],frameColor:#333333,bgColor:#FFFFFF,imageCaptions:[]}" pluginspage="HERE IS LINK TO://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" scale="exactfit" flash_component="ImageViewer.swc" wmod="transparent" >

Still does not work with safari (at least my version which is 5.1.2)

I was also tought of removing the white background which was added automatically but that caused the code to not work in the other browsers as well.

Thanks if you find some time to look at this that would be great.

Kat

Comment: You seem to have a spelling mistake on the name of the parameter, change this: 'wmod','transparent' to: 'wmode', 'transparent' in the last part of the tag code (second to last parameter before the //end AC code)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are embedding the swf movie (the flash object) with the parameter **wmode** set to `transparent`. Take a look at this for more info: [Google Chrome, Flash and z-index wrong behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313364/google-chrome-flash-and-z-index-wrong-behaviour)

There should be no need to decrease the z-index of the flash object (what you could do is to set the z-index of the div containing it) because default is 0 anyway.

Comment: Thank you Danii for your reply, I have tried that but unfortunately I tried that and it still does not work. (maybe I am doing it wrong?)

Comment: sorry danii, all this posting is very confusing, I have extended my questions as an edit, I would appreciate if you could take a look